# Strtok operations on Arduino Zero seem to fail in runtime

Tags: arduino-zero

I am trying to test functionality of strtok() on a new piece of hardware, as I ran out of memory to develop on my Nano. This is a basic example from the internet involving tokenizing the string and reporting the tokenized entries via SerialUSB. I'm running a [Rocketscream V3](https://www.rocketscream.com/blog/product/mini-ultra-pro-v3-with-radio/) (Arduino Zero ATSAMD21G18A).

```
#include <string.h>

void setup() {
  char *token;
  char *mystring = "apples,pears,bananas";

  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
  while (!SerialUSB) { }

  SerialUSB.print("Serial established");

  token = strtok(mystring, ",");
  
  while (token != NULL) {
    SerialUSB.println(token);
    token=strtok(NULL, ",");
  }
}
```

The code works as expected on my Nano (with Serial instead of SerialUSB), but while it does compile for the Arduino Zero, the Zero never makes it past printing "Serial established". I have confirmed this by including code (serial print, LED flashing) past the tokenization parts, and these are never executed. The loop() function is never reached, it seems to halt at "token = strtok(mystring, ",");".

I cannot think of a simpler possible way to test strtok(), but it's just not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` works by modifying the source string. Your test string points to a constant string.

```
  char *mystring = "apples,pears,bananas";
```

This particular platform may put that into read-only memory. Try instead as your test string:

```
  char mystring [] = "apples,pears,bananas";
```

I don't have a Zero to test it on, but in any case using `strtok` on a const string is <s>not recommended</s> forbidden.

---

If you turn warnings on for the compiler (File -> Preferences) you see this:

```
 In function 'void setup()':
 warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   char *mystring = "apples,pears,bananas";
```

If you are doing something "forbidden" then don't expect good results.

Comment: You mean `char mystring[] = "apples,pears,bananas";`.

Comment: Oh, and it's way worse than “not recommended”. It is “[undefined behavior](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs)”.

Comment: The compiler should at least be warning, if not giving an error, for passing a const string to a pointer to char.

Comment: Ah, it does if you turn warnings on.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Yes, a little typo there. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Nick_Gammon, I didn't realize I had warnings turned off.  That was all I needed. So, the code as written is undefined behavior, but why does it successfully execute on Nano? Just a quirk of how it handles memory during runtime?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, by definition, will behave in unexpected (or indeed, undefined) ways. The Nano may not care that you are writing to read-only memory.